# Universal Const in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React project with two separate components, a Header and a Sidebar. On the header there is a button which should collapsed the sidebar. I tried setting up a boolean const that would toggle a class in the Sidebar component, making the Sidebar collapsed. The only way I can think of doing this is a universal constant. Is this possible in React and/or is there a better/other way of achieving this other than merging the two components into one?

Comment: Hi! Please add some code of what you have tried, and why it isn't working for you. You might also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context api using useContext hook. The shared state can be defined in the parent component like your layout and accessed in sidebar and header..

Hope it helps

Comment: Probably overkill ***unless*** the header and sidebar are declared in completely different parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move the state to the parent, something along those lines:

```
function NavBar() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar className={isOpen && "isOpen"} />
            <NavToggle onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} />
        </>
    );
}

function NavToggle(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Toggle nav!</button>
}
```